# Render a table body in react using the map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to the `react.` Here I have a data that is in the array.Now
I want to render that table data.using the map function, what I tried is ,

```
    <tbody>
                { this.props.jobList.length > 0 &&  this.props.jobList.content.map(function (item, key) {
                  return (
                    <tr key={key}>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>3</td>
                      <td>4</td>
                      <td>5</td>
                      <td>6</td>
                      <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                })}
</tbody>

{
    "content": [{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd00507501051",
        "hrmsJdId": null,
        "companyId": null}]
}
```

Here, I do have data in the jobList but still it does not render that td content. Can any one explain me How can I do this? Or where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `jobList` is an array or `jobList.content`?

Comment: jobList is an array and content is an object

Comment: You must map over `jobList` then, instead of `jobList.content` since map is defined on an array

Comment: Do parenthesis help? `{ (this.props.jobList.length > 0) &&  this.props.jobList.content.map(function`

Comment: If `jobList` is an array then map through it . Is `jobList.content` an array ?

Comment: I have used this but still it is not showing the data in the table ,

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly your data looks like and what you want to display

Comment: I have just updated my question

Comment: @ganeshkaspate, the data that you just updated your question with, is it an object within jobList array or its jobList itself. also do you want to render the table with content?

Comment: yes I want to render the table with the content which is an array inside an object this.props.jobsList

Answer (score 1):

You should map your array data (`this.props.jobList`) instead of object. `render` should be like this:

```
<tbody>
    {this.props.jobList && this.props.jobList.content && this.props.jobList.content.length > 0 && this.props.jobList.content.map((item, key) => {
        return (
            <tr key={key}>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Actually now it is not giving any error but it is not showing that data

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Please give me your `this.props.jobList ` data

Comment: Actually this.props.jobList is an object in which  content is an array of objects

Comment: @ganeshkaspate could you please post your example data of `this.props.jobList`

Comment: Updated the data

Comment: @ganeshkaspate I have updated my answer, please try it.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. I do have one more question that if the data is coming from the diff props for the diff row element like first td is from some another props second is from some another out of seven 4 elements data is coming from one props and other is coming from another prop then How should I handle this condition

Comment: Before you display the results in table make a dummy array of required data from different props and then use a map function on newly created array to display the table.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate please mark my answer as resolved if it helps. With your extra question, please give me an example, your condition is very confusing, I don't understand what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do like this:

```
var {jobList} = this.props;
var result = null;
if(jobList.length >0){
   result = jobList.map(value,key){
       return (
          <tr key={key}>
             <td>{value.content.id}</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
             <td>6</td>
             <td>7</td>
          </tr>
       );
   }
}
return (
    <tbody>
        {result}
    </tbody>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and the data that you provided, it seems that you need to render contents within jobList for which you need to make use of nested map like

```
<tbody>
    {this.props.jobList && this.props.jobList.length > 0 && this.props.jobList.map((item, key) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
             {item.content.map(job => (
                  <tr key={job.id}>
                     <td>id: {job.id}</td>
                     <td>company: {job.company}</td>
                   </tr>
             ))}
          </React.Fragment>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: No Its giving me the length of undefined

Comment: This is not rendering the table data

Comment: Do you use version 16 of React? Also do you get any error

Comment: Yes I am using the version 16 as it has the fragment

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I tested inside a class based component.

```
render()
{
    return(
        <tbody>
            {this.props.jobList && this.props.jobList.content && this.props.jobList.content.length > 0 && this.props.jobList.content.map((item, key) => {
                    return(
                    <tr key={key}>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                )

            })}


        </tbody>    
    
    )

}
```

Looks interesting too, especially for people just starting in react. Makes the organized syntax a bit more comprehensive.